# MySQL UPDATE query - dealing with empty inputs

Tags: php, mysql

This is my first UPDATE query, I have checked using jQuery for any empty fields. I want the user to input at least one field and then update the field(s). Doing a query with all the $_POST names might generate empty or undefined input fields in my database which doesn't work.. here is my query:

```
$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$birth = $_POST['birth'];
$bio = $_POST['bio'];

$UID = $_SESSION['id'];

$query = "UPDATE `user` SET `firstname`=$first,`lastname`=$last,`birthday`=$birth,`biography`=$bio WHERE `user_id` = '$UID'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die($result . "<br/><br/>" . mysql_error());
```

The error:
**syntax to use near '`birthday`=,`biography`= WHERE `user_id` = '11'' at line 1**

I don't want to go through nested if's to check whether has a value or not. Thanks.

Comment: Please use prepared statements to avoid SQL injections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE: Use mysql_real_escape_string() to prevent from sql injection.**

```
if( !empty($first) && 
    !empty($last) && 
    !empty($birth) && 
    !empty($bio) ){

$query = "UPDATE `user` 
             SET 
               `firstname`='$first',
               `lastname`='$last',
               `birthday`='$birth', 
               `biography`='$bio' 
           WHERE `user_id` = '$UID'";
}
```

Comment: ok this is working, but they are updating the empty fields, so I have to check for this one?

Comment: @Atieh yes you have to check empty fields before update, otherwise it update empty value on every refresh, check the updated answer.

Comment: I got the idea, but this isn't my case, if it's empty I will set it to the current value..thanks!